# I Cant get an image to be resized and displayed using tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So im trying to make an app that will display images, and the image I have is 1000*1000 but this is way too big, I need a way to resize the image. I've tried using PIL and ImageTK but that didn't work, here's my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.title('embeded image')

fname = Canvas(bg = 'black', height=100, width=100)
fname.pack(side=TOP)

image = PhotoImage('Sun.png')
image = image.resize((25, 25), Image.ANTIALIAS)

icon = fname.create_image(image=image)

fname.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

I've no idea why this doesn't work, im relatively new to Tkinter so sorry if it's obvious.

Comment: did you run in in console to see error message ? It shows that `image` doesn't have `resize()` method. `tkinter` has `PhotoImage` to display image and it doesn't have `resize()`, and `PIL` has `Image` which have `resize()` - so you mix two different elements.

Answer (score 1):

You mix two differnt class `PhotoImage` in `tkinter` which doesn't have `resize` and `PIL.Image` which have `resize`

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

app = tk.Tk()

fname = tk.Canvas(height=200, width=200)
fname.pack()

pil_image = Image.open('Sun.png')
pil_image = pil_image.resize((25, 25), Image.ANTIALIAS)

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
icon = fname.create_image((0,0), image=image, anchor='nw')

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: if i try this it returns: No module named ImageTk, like i said above i tried ImageTk but it didnt work, do you have any information as to how i could insall it. looking on the internet, theres not alot of information about this at all.

Comment: you didn't say why it doesn't work - so I assumed you have it but you don't know have to use it. Install `Pillow` using `pip install pillow`